# ToString argument is wrong

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, textbox, tostring

I would like to get some help : I can't get values form SQL Database to WPF textbox.
I tried by myself many codes that didn't worked, and this one looks fine but ".ToString" argument **is wrong**.

What should i put instead ?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATE_A FROM Donnees_Accueil", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    hourA.Text = sqlReader["Date_A"].ToString;
                }

                sqlReader.Close();
            }
```

Thank you in advance,
Zancrew.

Comment: You want `.ToString();` not `.ToString;`. It's a method, not a field/property.

Comment: You're trying to access `.ToString;` as if it is a property, not a method. Add parentheses to the end to make it `.ToString();`

Comment: The compiler doesn't just say "ToString is wrong". It gives you a very specific message that you can research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `ToString()` is a *method*, not *property*, that's why `()` is required; if you want to *concat* all the records:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnString))
{
    con.Open(); 

    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATE_A FROM Donnees_Accueil", con)) 
    {
        using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Date_A"])); 
            }  

            hourA.Text = sb.ToString(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

If you want to get the *1st record* only:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnString))
{
    con.Open(); 

    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DATE_A FROM Donnees_Accueil", con)) 
    {
        using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (sqlReader.Read())
                hourA.Text = Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Date_A"]);
            else  
                hourA.Text = "";
        } 
    }
}
```